# Jayway JsonPath query to get required json format

Tags: java, jsonpath

I need to extract a json in required format from input json. i'm using jayway json path library. How to achieve it ?

**Input Json:**

```
 { 
        "ccid": [
            {
                "id": 13,           
                "src": {
                    "sname": "XA-SXXD",
                    "lname": "John",
                    "identifier": 2,
                    "StatusCode": "C"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 14,            
                "src": {
                    "sname": "XB-SXXD",
                    "lname": "Cena",
                    "identifier": 3,
                    "StatusCode": "C",
                }
            }
            ]
    }
```

**Required Format:**

> [ {
>           "id": "13",
>           "sources": {
>             "sname": "XA-SXXD",
>             "lname": "John",
>             "identifier": 2
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           "id": "14",
>           "sources": {
>              "sname": "XB-SXXD",
>              "lname": "Cena",
>              "identifier": 3
>           }
>       }]

Query that i use:

```
$.ccid[*].src[?(@.identifier!=null)].['identifier','sname']
```

Output that i get:

```
[
   {
      "identifier" : 2,
      "sname" : "XA-SXXD"
   },
   {
      "identifier" : 3,
      "sname" : "XB-SXXD"
   }
]
```

Kindly help me to modify my query to get the required format. The string "sources" in the required format can be hardcoded.

Comment: since you are trying to return that is of type JSON Array you would get a result type as JSONArray.

Comment: Ok..I edited my question. Check now.. even I want the output as array. But how do i add the id  and src tag

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve this :)

`$.ccid[*].[?(@.src.identifier!=null)].['id', 'src']`

Give it a try.

Input tested on:

```
{ 
        "ccid": [
            {
                "id": 13,           
                "src": {
                    "sname": "XA-SXXD",
                    "lname": "John",
                    "StatusCode": "C"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 14,            
                "src": {
                    "sname": "XB-SXXD",
                    "lname": "Cena",
                    "identifier": null,
                    "StatusCode": "C",
                }
            }
            ]
    }
```

Output received:

```
[
   {
      "id" : 13,
      "src" : {
         "sname" : "XA-SXXD",
         "lname" : "John",
         "StatusCode" : "C"
      }
   }
]
```

Only problem is saw is if identifier tag is not available it's essentially treated as not-null. Hence we are getting 13 as an output. But if value is explicitly null then it's fine. So the needs to be enhanced a bit more.

Hope this helps.